# Software for backing up SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, backup, windows

Since using the new version of Symantec, I've experienced lots of problems doing incremental backups of clients' SQL databases.

Is Windows Server backup a good alternative to Symantec Backup Exec 2012 for backing up SQL databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the best product for performing SQL backups is SQL Server itself.  When space permits, I backup to local disk (full + differential, tx log backups every 10 minutes).  These files can then be backed up by your third party software (to tape, NAS, etc.).

If I need to do an emergency restore (assuming a non-drive related issue), I already have the files local to the server, no need to mess around with restoring from tape or copying across a network.

One client of mine had used a third party software to backup files directly to tape (a proprietary format).  Two years later they needed to do a restore (audit).  They had a great deal of difficulty performing the restore because in the meantime they had upgraded the OS and the backup software, which no longer was compatible with the tapes they had from before.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Server backup is probably the worst choice you can make. It is not specifically made for SQL backup and people report all kind of problems with it. More common is to use SQL Server Agent for SQL backups. But this is a poor choice too. First - it is not available in Express, the interface stayed practically the same for 12 years and is not user-friendly. Configuring email notifications is a nightmare, compression and encryption do not exist and there are no options to send backups to popular cloud storages. There are tons of 3rd party software that can do the job much easier.

[SqlBak](http://sqlbak.com) - an online service to schedule any types of backup (in standard format), send them to FTP, Dropbox, OneDrive, Azure, etc and restore just from a browser [Disclosure: I am affiliated with SqlBak]

[SQLBackupAndFTP](http://SQLBackupAndFTP.com) - a desktop application that does the same [Disclosure: I am affiliated with SQLBackupAndFTP]

Other popular choices are HandyBackup, iBackup, Litespeed,  - all of them will do the job better than the built-in MS tools.